# Отображение галереи wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Всем привет.

Вроде бы проблема простая, но я её так и не смог решить и решил всё откатить и сделать резервную копию и базы данных sql и структуры сайта. Но при установке на локальный сервер, увидел, что проблема с отображением галереи решена. Естественно, я на радостях, тоже самое сделал на основном хостинге и паник. Как такое возможно, что там всё есть, но на локальном сервере запускается всё с помощью `http://` а на основном `https://`, но я решил проверить в этом ли проблема, как оказалось нет!

Что может быть причиной, что мешает и сбивает отображение галереи, я хочу решить эту проблему и если дело не в правке CSS, тогда верну всё на круги своя и восстановлю прежний вид и дизайн сайта.
Изображения и ссылки:

1. http://prntscr.com/lwatwq - отображение галереи на локальном сервере
2. http://prntscr.com/lwauf0 - отображение на основном хостинге
3. https://hotplus.com.ua/2014/09/our-agency-can-distribute-your-flyers-and-enlarge-the-number-of-customers/ - ссылка для того, чтоб вы сами убедились и увидели.

И дополнительный вопрос, обычно в админ-панели WordPress, можно зайти в раздел постоянные ссылки и установить тот формат постоянных ссылок, который мы захотим. В моём случае, когда я нажимаю на нужный мне формат отображения, а именно "Название записи https://hotplus.com.ua/sample-post/" и нажимаю сохранить, прото ничего не изменяет и остаётся как и прежде. Это как понять, что ему мешает?

Ссылка:

1. http://prntscr.com/lwawae - после изменения остаётся и не меняется.

Заблаговременно, спасибо за Ваши подсказки.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что из-за этого - /2014/09/, но я могу ошибаться. А проверить это не могу)) Наверно плагин, предназначенный для этой темы, который активирован, просто блокирует это всё..., пока не знаю.

Comment: У вас на сервере не грузится файл стилей - 404. Загляните в консоль.

Comment: Здесь не принято задавать несколько вопросов в одном. Создайте второй вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: Ну зачем плодить темы, итак всё вполне понятно. Правильно? Ну вот. А что касается стилей, я в консоли этого не вижу "У вас на сервере не грузится файл стилей - 404", даже не знаю, где это Вы увидели. И как решается данная проблема.

Comment: Наверно много текста накалякал, пользователь нынче ленивый и не любит читать..., вот и за 15 часов, всего один ответ.

Comment: Неправильно. Есть правила сообщества, и их надо соблюдать. Придуманы они не просто так. Один пост - один вопрос.

Comment: В браузере нажмите F12, откроется панель разработчика (dev tools). Там выберите консоль и посмотрите на ошибки. Увидите 404. Наведите курсов на имя файла, увидите полный путь к нему: http://take.ms/Ffy9h